# C declaring an arrayList in .h file

Tags: c++, arraylist

Hi I am pretty new to C++ I'm  a lot more used to Java. But what I want to do is create just an empty arrayList that can be used by all of my other functions.

In my .h file I created a new class which has 2 structs within it and about 6 methods. Each of these methods uses arrayLists of the struct objects, but I don't want to have to pass in the arrayLists as parameters. What I am trying to do is similar to in Java when you create a field in a class.

The problem is when I declare the arrayList like this in my .h file...

```
structObject * myArrayList = new structObject[0];
int ARRAY_SIZE = arrayList.size;
```

I get a bunch of errors including `new cannot be declared in a constant`.

Where should I be trying to declare my empty arraylist? 
Is this even permissible in C++?

Comment: There's no `arrayList` class in C++ (unless you've written one yourself).  The C++ class that's most similar to Java's `ArrayList` is `std::vector`.

Comment: Error is not caused by the code you shown. Post the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to put a definition in a header file. That is a not allowed. You can only put declarations in a header file.

declaration in the header:

```
structObject* myArrayList;
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100
```

definition in a source file:

```
myArrayList = new structObject[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

However, global variables are almost always a bad idea. I would find a way to pass the array as an argument to the necessary functions. You should also look into the Standard Template Library and look at different containers.

one option:

```
std::vector<structObject> myArrayList;
```

That can be put in a header file, and the constructor will do necessary initialization.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an ArrayList class built into C++.  Look into the `std::vector` class.